# Nil values returned from 'didset' JSON decoded array data

Tags: ios, json, swift

I can't seem to set the television shows and thumbnails images below. I'm generating the array of data correctly as the print(shows) statement correctly prints all the items. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong. There are no errors, but my views are coming up empty with no image or title. 
Here is the TvController class

```
class TvController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var tvShows: [RecentTvList]? = []


func fetchTvItems()   {

    let jsonUrlString = "https://www.what-song.com/api/recent-tv?page=1"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else
    {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {

            let shows =  try
                JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvListData.self, from: data)
            print(shows)

            self.tvShows = shows.data

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }

    }.resume()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchTvItems()

    navigationItem.title = "TV"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white

    collectionView?.register(TvCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView?.register(Header.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:
        UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = tvShows?.count    {
        return count
    }

    return 0

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TvCell

    cell.televisionShow = tvShows?[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
}
```

Here is the model file:

```
struct RecentTvListData: Decodable  {
var data: [RecentTvList]
}

struct RecentTvList: Decodable  {
var title: String?
var poster_url: String?
}
```

Here is the View for the cell: All the views/subviews/constraints are set up correctly, I just didn't bother including the code because it makes all of this too bloated. I'm very sure the problem lies in either the model or controller.

```
var tvShowsController: TvController?


var televisionShow: RecentTvList? {
    didSet {
        titleLabel.text = televisionShow?.title
        setupThumbnailImage()
        thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(named: (televisionShow?.poster_url)!)
    }
}

let thumbnailImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "stranger things poster"))
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()

let titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let title = UILabel()
    title.text = "Stranger Things"
    title.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat", size: 17)
    title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return title
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading the data (i.e. all the code in the block following `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)`) is an asynchronous operation, which means that iOS runs that code on a different thread where it has as much time as it needs to finish and immediately continues execution of the current (main, in this case) thread. When your collection view loads and attempts to show its data, it hasn't finished downloading yet, so there's no data to show. You can force your collection view to load your data once it's finished downloading by calling `reloadData`, like this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

    guard let data = data else {return}

    do {

        let shows =  try
            JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvListData.self, from: data)
        print(shows)

        self.tvShows = shows.data
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    } catch let jsonErr {
        print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
    }

}.resume()
```

Comment: It is not a UIViewController. He is subclassing UICollectionViewController. There is no need to set delegate and dataSource

Comment: Ah, thanks, I overlooked that. I removed that part of my answer

Comment: Ahhhh thank you soooo much! Really appreciate, I've been trying to figure it out for hours :S